# Topbar issue in Chrome, name or picture not appearing

Tags: support, google-chrome, top-bar, imgur

In Chrome, name or picture thumbnail not appearing beside reputation and badges at top bar.

See the capture below:

[image]

Comment: Name is not there. Are you talking about name as a tooltip when we hover on the image? And both work fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: Norepo here, too. Maybe some problems with accessing imgur?

Comment: No repro here as well. Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: i am using Version 31.0.1650.57 m. Capture is visible ??

Comment: Refresh. Hard refresh. Clear cache and refresh. Works 99% of the times. :)

Comment: @AhsanShah can you see your profile picture elsewhere?

Comment: @AhsanShah - We are too talking about the same. We can see our thumbnail on topbar.

Comment: +1 to @ShaWizDowArd, I had to do a hard refresh on my FF when the new bar was deployed. (Off-topic, but I'll soon lose count of the times I typed *@Shad<tab>*)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: you are right. i cant see my uploaded picture any ware else. it is showing white box.

Comment: @AhsanShah can you see other profile pictures (specifically those hosted on imgur and nor gravatar images).  I have a problem at work where imgur images are blocked when I use Chrome, but not Firefox or IE.

Comment: @AhsanShah this means `imgur.com` domain is blocked for you. Guess you browse from work? In such case I fear there's nothing you can do except using Gravatar, then you'll see your own picture. (but not many others)